# How can I calculate overlaps in Pandas dataframe scoped to groups

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract overlapping events in an dataframe which contains a grouping criteria of the events.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'event': ['event1', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event5', 'event6', 'event7', 'event8'],
    'time_start': ['2000-01-01 08:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 07:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 11:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 12:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 13:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 08:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 07:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 08:30:00'
                   ],
    'time_end': ['2000-01-01 09:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 10:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 12:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 13:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 14:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 09:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 09:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 10:00:00'
                 ]
})
```

| id | group | event | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | event1 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 |
| 2 | a | event2 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 |
| 3 | a | event3 | 2000-01-01 11:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 4 | a | event4 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 13:30:00 |
| 5 | a | event5 | 2000-01-01 13:00:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 6 | b | event6 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 |
| 7 | b | event7 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 09:30:00 |
| 8 | b | event8 | 2000-01-01 08:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |

event1 + event2 and event4 + event5 are overlapping in group 'a', and event6, event7, event8 are overlapping in group 'b'.
The events of group 'a' do not overlap with events of group 'b'.

The result which I try to achieve is the following:

| id | group | event | time_start | time_end | overlap | time_start_overlap | time_end_overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | event1 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 | 10 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 |
| 2 | a | event2 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 | 10 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 |
| 3 | a | event3 | 2000-01-01 11:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 | 3 | 2000-01-01 11:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 4 | a | event4 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 13:30:00 | 11 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 5 | a | event5 | 2000-01-01 13:00:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 | 11 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 6 | b | event6 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 | 12 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 7 | b | event7 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 09:30:00 | 12 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 8 | b | event8 | 2000-01-01 08:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 | 12 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |

The column overlap 'marks' the rows which belong to the same overlap, and the columns time_start_overlap and time_end_overlap is the period of that overlap, which includes the period of the event.

I can get it working when there is only one group (e.g. name = 'a'), but when multiple groups are involved I struggle. Here is the code I was able to assemble:

```
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['time_start'], df['time_end'], closed='both')
overlaps = [iix.overlaps(x) for x in iix if iix.overlaps(x).sum()>1]

df['overlap'] = df.index
i = len(df)+1
for overlap in overlaps:
    df['overlap'] = df['overlap'].where(~overlap, other=i, inplace=False)
    i+=1

g = df.groupby(['group', 'overlap']).agg(
    time_start_overlap = ('time_start', min),
    time_end_overlap = ('time_end', max)
)
df = pd.merge(df, g, on=['group', 'overlap'])
```

Leading to the following result. It can be seen that overlap 15 marks events both from group a and b, where as I want to tread them as separate groups and separate overlaps.

| id | group | event | time_start | time_end | overlap | time_start_overlap | time_end_overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | event1 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 | 15 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 |
| 2 | a | event2 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 | 15 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:30:00 |
| 3 | a | event3 | 2000-01-01 11:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 | 3 | 2000-01-01 11:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 4 | a | event4 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 13:30:00 | 12 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 5 | a | event5 | 2000-01-01 13:00:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 | 12 | 2000-01-01 12:30:00 | 2000-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 6 | b | event6 | 2000-01-01 08:00:00 | 2000-01-01 09:00:00 | 15 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 7 | b | event7 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 09:30:00 | 15 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 8 | b | event8 | 2000-01-01 08:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 | 15 | 2000-01-01 07:30:00 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |

Comment: what does value of overlap column mean? 10? 2? 11?

Comment: In the case of event 3, for example, why you want the `time_start_overlap` and `time_end_overlap` to still show something even though that event does not overlap with any of the events in its group (`a`)? How would you distinguish an event that only overlaps with itself (like `event3`) from one that also overlap with some other event?

Comment: Also, based on your output example I cannot understand exactly what you want in `time_start_overlap` and `time_end_overlap`. Right now it looks like you want `time_start_overlap` to be the earliest start time among all the events that overlap in each group, and `time_end_overlap` to be the latest end time among all the events that overlap in each group. Is that what you really want?

Comment: kindly add the code you use for computing the results for a single group

Comment: @PandaKim there is no meaning on overlap, it is just an indicator which events overlap. I used ids < len(df)+1 and assigned them to the overlapping rows. Oh, overlap 2 is actually overlap 3, as I propagate the id (=index) initially to the overlap column. Afterwards overlap is reassigned on overlaps using an IntervalIndex.

Comment: @atteggiani I just put the values of `time_*` to `time_*_overlap` to have an easier processing afterwards. E.g. to sum up the busy times of the group. Otherweise I need to fetch the timestamps from different columns.
Regarding your second comment: yes, I really want to have the whole span of the overlapping events. When there is e.g. a 4th event in group `a`, lets say `2023-01-01 12:30:00` to `2023-01-01 13:30:00` and a 5th, overlapping with the 4th, then the 4th and 5th event should get a) a new overlap id, and b) `time_start_overlap` and `time_end_overlap` derived from those two events.

Comment: @sammywemmy will add the code when back home.

Comment: @Joysn Ok but it still a bit unclear. What if you have `event9` in the group `a` with `time_start = 2023-01-01 6:30:00` and `time_start = 2023-01-01 7:45:00` (So it overlaps with event2). Then the `time_start_overlap` for `event2` would be `2023-01-01 6:30:00` right? But what about the `overlap` column (which I still haven't really understood how to compute)??

Comment: @atteggiani Sorry for the typo, it should have been 2000, not 2023. I corrected the example data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok based on the discussion and on your output, I think the code below will work for you.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'event': ['event1', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event5', 'event6', 'event7', 'event8'],
    'time_start': ['2000-01-01 08:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 07:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 11:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 12:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 13:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 08:00:00',
                   '2000-01-01 07:30:00',
                   '2000-01-01 08:30:00'
                   ],
    'time_end': ['2000-01-01 09:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 10:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 12:00:00',
                 '2023-01-01 13:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 14:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 09:00:00',
                 '2000-01-01 09:30:00',
                 '2000-01-01 10:00:00'
                 ]
})

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

def to_date(datastr):
    return dt.strptime(datastr,fmt)

def to_datestr(date):
    return dt.strftime(date,fmt)

df['overlap'] = 0
df['time_start_overlap'] = df['time_start'] 
df['time_end_overlap'] = df['time_end']

for r in df.index:
    cond = np.logical_and.reduce([
        df.loc[r,'group'] == df['group'],
        df.loc[r,'time_start'] <= df['time_end'], 
        df.loc[r,'time_end'] >= df['time_start']
        ])
    start =  to_datestr(min(df[cond]['time_start'].apply(to_date)))
    end =  to_datestr(max(df[cond]['time_end'].apply(to_date)))
    indices = pd.Series([df[cond].index.tolist() for _ in df.index])
    df['overlap'].where(~cond,indices,inplace=True)
    df['time_start_overlap'].where(~cond,start,inplace=True)
    df['time_end_overlap'].where(~cond,end,inplace=True)
```

Since I did not understand well what your `overlap` column is supposed to compute, I assigned a list with the indices of all the overlapping events among the same group.
In case you want to change this, just change the line `indices = pd.Series([df[cond].index.tolist() for _ in df.index])` to something that works for you.

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Cheers
Davide

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Did not know about np.logical_and.reduce. The indices for the overlap you provide is way better than the number I used. I will use the overlap column for filtering. But I noticed one issue. The last row gets NaN as overlap. Although the time_start_overlap and time_end_overlap columns are set correctly. Why does this happen?

Comment: I converted the indices to a string like '1, 2', then the NaN on the last rows overlap disappeared. I furthermore changed the for loop to a while loop, set overlap to x and reevaluate the remaining rows not yet processed using `while not df.index[df["overlap"] == 'x'].empty:`. This avoids processing already processed rows. Thank you for the idea using `np.logical_and.reduce`. :)

Comment: Not reprocessing the already processed rows might incur in an issue. Take your example: if you have `event9` in the group `a` with `time_start = 2000-01-01 6:30:00` and `time_end = 2000-01-01 7:45:00` (So it overlaps only with `event2`). Then the `time_start_overlap` for `event2` would have to be `2000-01-01 6:30:00`. But `event2`'s `time_start_overlap` gets set to `2000-01-01 7:30:00` after the first loop (because it overlaps with `event1`). If you don't re-process `event2`, its `time_start_overlap` would stay `2000-01-01 7:30:00` at the end of the program and be wrong.

Comment: You are right. I tried it by adding `event9`.  But, interestingly, `event1` overlaps with `event9`, but `event9` does not overlap with `event1`. Timewise, there is no overlap between these two events.